# REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED from Salesforce.com API

Tags: governorlimits

All my code is bulkified and I'm not sure what is causing that to get me the limit exceeded, is there a way to find out what page or trigger causing?

if I use `Database.query` approach will that not consider API call?

```
employee = Database.query("select id,name from employee__c where employeeId = 123");
```

vs.

```
employee = ["select id,name from employee__c where employeeId = 123"];
```

Comment: Are you using the dev console? If so it eats up a lot of API calls and if you are in a DE org you can hit the limit

Comment: Yes I'm mostly on dev console when I want to cross check the query quickly, what is the better way?

Comment: What is `DE` ? you mean development environment?

Comment: Yes... Close the Dev console when you are not using it. When developing an app or code in a DE environment that uses API calls, having the Dev console open and running your code can cause you to exceed your limit. You only get like 5000 api calls in a 24 hour period so it adds up fast when debugging / developing

Comment: I have 15k api limit but that surprisingly i have exceeded in less then 24 hours and some times i have two dev console windows opened... is there a way you can point me the site that dev console eats up lot of api calls?

Comment: Just open the dev console and review the API calls used before and after. It uses the tooling and Metadata API so it uses calls. I opened the Dev console and ran a single test and API calls went from 0 to 24. That was in the span of 30 seconds. 1 minutes later just keeping dev console open and it used 10 more. I do not have documentation, just experience

Comment: @Eric, I am sorry if I should this post as new question but could you please tell me where to monitor the number of API calls in developer console? Thanks

Comment: You can;t see it in the dev console, you have to goto setup -> Company information. Refresh the screen to get the new Api counts as needed